# Symfony: Best place to catch exception (CQRS/DDD)

Tags: php, symfony

I've a personal application. I use design pattern CQRS/DDD for a API.

**Schema**:
User --> Controller (dispatch command) --> Command handler --> some services...

In my Rest API controller

```
$this->dispatch($cmd);
```

If a throw a exception in services or specification classes for example, ok, I've a listener to catch exception and create JSON response error.

But if I want to develop an interface module with TWIG, I think I will not use my listener because I don't want a JSON response.

Should I used try/catch in my controller of my new interface module ?

```
SomeController extends AbstractController
{
    public function getObject($id)
    {
         try {
            $this->dispatch($cmd);
        catch(SomeException $ex) {
            $this->render(....)
        } 
    }
}
```

**Where is the best place to catch exception for TWIG ?**

Thanks.

**Edit:**

@Cid
*if (some conditions && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) --> My handler don't return bool or values.*

Imagine this code. Imagine I want share a service between an API and web view app.

```
class ApiController
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->dispatch($cmd);
    }
}

class WebController
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->dispatch($cmd);
    }
}

class SomeHandler implements CommandHandlerInterface
{

    /** @required */
    public RegisterService $service;

    public function __invoke(SomeCommand $command)
    {
        $this->service->register($command->getEmail())
    }
}

class RegisterService
{
    public function register(string $email)
    {
        // Exception here
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of exceptions? are they Symfony exceptions, related with some HTTP code?

Comment: Nop, for example : an user want to register in my application from a form view. In my service I check If username, email isn't exist. I throw exception If email already exist.

Comment: In that example, what kind of template you want to render? The register view with the error message?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: I think you are complicating yourself, Symfony already handle that. I suppose in your register controller, you have something like : `if (some conditions && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) { /* add the user */ return someRoute } return render the register view`. `$form` already contains error messages (generated by `$form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()`) that can be used in views `{{ form_label(form.user.email, "Email", {'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label'}}) }}` already contains a potential error message

Comment: *"In my service I check If username, email isn't exist."* If you're using an ORM, such as Doctrine, it already does that for you, if you use an annotation such as `@ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false, unique=true)` And it checks for empty fields, thanks to the `nullable=false` attribute. Everything is checked when calling the method `isValid()`

Comment: Look my new Post. I use CQRS. This example is very simple.
Another example : Imagine an app with some teams to talk. 
You can send email invitation to your friend to join yout team. 
My service check 
if your friend is not already in team, 
if you have already send a invitation, 
if your friend is already in team... and each cases throw an exception.

Comment: To me, this is a CQRS question and not a Symfony question.  You say you have an exception handler for your api.  Seems like you could have a different handler for your web.  But from a big picture point of view, using exceptions to control program flow tends to get messy real quick.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think the best place to handle Exception is EventSubscriber, see here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-exception

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;

public function onKernelException(ExceptionEvent $event)
{
    $exception = $event->getThrowable();
    $response = new Response();
    // setup the Response object based on the caught exception
    $event->setResponse($response);

    // you can alternatively set a new Exception
    // $exception = new \Exception('Some special exception');
    // $event->setThrowable($exception);
}
```

Comment: Yes, for API is good, but for web app use TWIG ?

Comment: You can render template here and create response, Google: custom error Page Symfony